# What is the distance between the centre of the sphere and the vertex of the cone?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, spheres, convex-cone

> A hollow right circular cone rests on a sphere as shown in the figure. The height of the cone is $4$ metres and the radius of the base is $1$ metre. The volume of the sphere is same as that of the cone. What is the distance between the centre of the sphere and the vertex of the cone?

[image]

Since the volume of the sphere is same as the volume of the cone I found that the radius of the sphere is also $1$ metre and hence half of the sphere will be inside the cone i.e. the distance between the centre of the sphere and the vertex of the cone is same as the height of the cone which is given to be $4$ metres. Am I right?

Comment: What makes you think that half of the sphere is inside the cone? And by the way, if they have the same radius then the 3D picture is wrong.

Comment: @Sayed then how do they have same radius? Otherwise the radius of the sphere is strictly bigger than the cone. Isn't it?

Comment: Look at the picture, if half of the sphere is inside the cone then the tangent to the sphere must touch the edge of the cone's base. It is clearly visible that the radius of the cone is larger than the radius of the sphere.

Comment: But @Sayed these two radius are given to be same. Which can be proved by their same volume argument.

Comment: I was thinking about the picture not the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]No, the cone will touch the sphere before. We can easily see it is wrong. Let's assume exactly half of the sphere is inside the cone.

In that case, at height h from the center of the sphere to the vertex of the cone, radius of the circle in the sphere will be -

$$r_s=\sqrt{1^2-h^2}$$
Now,
$$\text {Also the radius of the cone at height h from the base, } r_c = \frac{4-h}{4}$$
Let's now assume h = 0.2.

$$\text {We get, } r_s > r_c$$

It should have been the other way round. That tells you that the cone will touch sphere at a circle above the equator.

Now to solve it, wherever cone will touch the sphere, the line from center of the sphere to the point of contact will be perpendicular to the edge of the cone. Let's say distance from vertex of the cone to the point of contact is distance a. Then,

$$\frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\text {So, } a = 4$$
$$\text {Distance from center of the sphere to the vertex of the cone } = \sqrt{1^2+a^2} = \sqrt{17}$$

Comment: Also what did you mean by $\frac 1 a = \frac 1 4$?

Comment: I added a picture. I hope now it is clear. Cone touches Sphere at point T1 and T2, Base of the cone (including points A and B ) is not in contact with the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Direct*

Equating cone and sphere volumes

$$ R_{sph} = (r^2h/4)^\frac13 $$

If $  h= 4r$ then $ R_{sph} = r $ then the assembly will look as in first part

Distance between centers $= h =4$

*Tangential Contact*

$$\angle BCT = \angle BTS $$

$$\dfrac{h}{CT}=\dfrac{CT}{D} ;\; CT^2 = h^2+ r^2=h \cdot D\;$$

$$ D= h+ \dfrac{r^2}{h} = 4+\dfrac14 = 4.25 $$

as shown in second part.

Comment: How do you get $h \cdot D = h^2 + r^2$? What I can see is that $$D = h + \sqrt {1-r^2}.$$

Comment: Also $r$ is definitely not $1$; Instead it should be less than $1$ since the corresponding circle is a small circle and radius of the sphere is $1.$ Don't post wrong solution please. Isn't your process misleading?

Comment: But $r < 1$ and hence $h < 4.$ Look at it carefully. Because the circle of intersection is situated above the centre of the sphere. So the radius of the circle of intersection should be less than the radius of the sphere which is $1.$ How did you miss that?

Comment: If $r=1$ and $h=4$ then by your own formula $CT^2 = h^2 + r^2 = 1^2 + 4^2 = 17.$ Note also that $D = \sqrt {1 + CT^2} = \sqrt {1+17} = \sqrt {18} = 3 \sqrt {2} \neq 4.25.$ So you have contradicted your own solution. How funny !

Comment: I understood that $R_{\text {sph}} = r \sqrt {1 + \frac {r^2} {h^2}}.$ But how did you compute it to be $1.03078$? How do you know $r$ and $h$? @Nar in which grade you currently in? Why do you post vague proof?

Comment: You again put $r=1$ and $h=4.$ Well suppose by some rescaling you did what you want then how is it inconsistent with the given problem? I don't understand your logic. What do you mean by "inconsistency" here?

Comment: Please avoid answering this question. Leave this immediately. Your reasoning seems quite ambiguous and flawed to me. My tolerance level have exceeded.

Comment: Yeah. So what. The cone is not ended by touching the sphere; You can think it of as a conical hat in your head. Does the edge of the conical hat ended only by touching your head?

Comment: @ Phi beta kappa It took me time to follow. I have now edited my answer. Please delete your comments to clean up. .

Comment: Look at Math lover's answer. So nice and logical and your's  Leave it. Leave it. Bye! Bye! Brother.